# ReferenceError: _spPageContextInfo is not defined

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, sharepoint-2013

I have the following code in my js file:

```
var configNews = {
    url:_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
    newsLibrary: 'DEMONews',
    listId: ''
};

// Getting the ListID
$.ajax({
    url: configNews.url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + configNews.newsLibrary + "')?$select=Id",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        // Returning the results
        configNews.listId = data.d.Id;
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

But I am getting the following error:
ReferenceError: _spPageContextInfo is not defined
I don't know where I am wrong and how to remove this error

Comment: `_spPageContextInfo` is not declared in your code, try to put `console.log(_spPageContextInfo)` will also give same error

Comment: Then what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: provide its value, how can i know, what would be the value of `_spPageContextInfo`

Comment: it must me something like `var _spPageContextInfo = { webAbsoluteUrl: 'https://something.com' }` this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is correct. But don't try to run it before page loaded.
_spPageContextInfo defined somewhere in body section. So, it`s not available in head section.

Just try to run your code on DOM ready, or put it at the end of the page.

Answer (score 5):

Since its a sharepoint code try running this:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js","ClientContext",functionName)
```

This ensures that the specified file (sp.js) that contains the specified function (ClientContext) is loaded and then runs the specified callback function name.

Realize that `SharePoints _spPageContextInfo` is being used before it gets auto initialized

Comment: Missing quotation marks...SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js","ClientContext",functionName)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error that _spPageContextInfo is not defined. I have spent over 3 days on this. Finally got it resolved, make sure that from your Modern Script Editor,**"Enable classic _spPageContextInfo" is enabled**

Refer to this image below to find where you may find the option to enable this option.

Please find this image here to enable the classic _spPageContextInfo:

How to enable the classic _spPageContextInfo

[image: 1]